# wont add form details to database or send me mail

Tags: wpdb, wp-mail

My order form stopped working ...it doesn't inserting data into the post-type orders as it should nor does it send me the email...i am using the plugin wp-mail-smtp to get it to send me the mails once an order is placed along with it trying to add the details of the order to the post-type order....but it does nothing however it does give the message thank you we contact you shortly.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function submitorder() {
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          window.location = "http://mytestsite.org/order";
        }
      }
    });
  });


  </script>

<article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 ">

<div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4 text-center bottom-pad">
<div class="text-center">
 <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal formpad " >       

    <div class="form-group">            
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <input type="text" id="inputName" name="leadname" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" height="34px">
            </div>
        </div> 

        <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <input type="text" id="inputEmail" name="leademail" placeholder="Email" class="form-control"  height="34px">
            </div>
        </div>  


        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <label class="text-left">Order Type</label> 
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 text-left">
                <input type="checkbox" value="0" name="order_type[]"> pens</input><br>
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="order_type[]"> books</input><br>
                <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="order_type[]"> papers</input><br>
                <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="order_type[]"> pencils</input><br>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group ">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn order-btn" onclick="submitorder();"><strong>Order Now!</strong></button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
 </div>
</div>

</article> 

<?php

$toemail="myemail@gmail.com";
$lead_name=$_POST['leadname'];
$lead_email=$_POST['leademail'];

$chk=array();
$planchk=array();
$headers=  'From: '.$lead_name.'<'.$lead_email .'>'. "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: '.$lead_email;

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    global $wpdb;
        if (empty($lead_name))
    {   

?>
    <div id="dialog-message" title="Alert">
        <p>
            Please enter your Name.
        </p> 
    </div>

    <?php     

    }
        elseif (empty($lead_email))
    {
    ?>

    <div id="dialog-message" title="Alert">
        <p>             
            Please enter your email.
        </p> 
    </div>

    <?php

    }
        else
        {
        $todaydate = new DateTime();
        $todaydate =$todaydate->format('Y-m-d H-i-s');
    $newpost= array('post_type'=>'orders',
                        'post_title'=>$lead_name,
            'post_author'=>'1',
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            'post_date'=>$todaydate );
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert('wp_posts',$newpost); 
    $newpostid=$wpdb->insert_id;
    update_field('lead_email',$lead_email,$newpostid);


    if(!empty($_POST['order_type']))
    {   
        foreach($_POST['order_type'] as $selectedorder)
        {       
        $chk[]=$selectedorder;      
        }
        update_field('field_55efacbc25266',$chk,$newpostid);        
    }   


?>

<div id="dialog-message" title="Thank You">
  <p>
        We will Contact you shortly
  </p> 
</div>


<?php
wp_mail($toemail,$selectedorder." ORDER query from " .$lead_name,"order",$headers);        
}
unset($_POST['submit']);
}

?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

plz note i have multiple sites on single hosting plan

Comment: did you send the test e-mail? Is it working

Comment: inside the plugin it has send test mail that yes,.it working...but from form its not working

Comment: which form you are using...?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
  * Since the install of WP-Mail-SMTP we need to make sure the FROM is 
    the same as the one specified in the plugin
  * These filters will overwrite any FROM send by other plugins.
  */
 add_filter('wp_mail_from','custom_wp_mail_from');
 function custom_wp_mail_from($email) {
     return get_option('mail_from');
  }

 add_filter('wp_mail_from_name','custom_wp_mail_from_name');
 function custom_wp_mail_from_name($name) {
    return get_option('mail_from_name');
  }
```

Might be this will help you....If you can make edit to the core..Use this code if you are working with gravity forms.

Comment: no this code i put above is added to page template thts assigned to a page to act as a form

Comment: Under mail section select the 'PHP mail()' function...

Comment: nop not working...plz note its not even adding the data to the posttype

Comment: use die() and check where is the actual problem...

Comment: where do i put die();

Comment: use from where your else part is going on...and use till you didn't get the problem..

Comment: ok i changed it to wp_insert_post and it inserts the code into the  db...but it still wont send me the mail alert

Comment: the add filter code u gave shud i add tht to the page template or to functions.php?

Comment: plz note i have multiple sites on single hosting plan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58237/discussion-between-mukii-kumar-and-sonia-k).